# How to show a custom message page to AWS Kibana users when he logs in first time without any roles assigned

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

How to show a custom message page to AWS Kibana users when he logs in first time without any roles assigned

Is there a way i can guide a new user that he doesnt have any roles assigned as of now and he can contact the admin.

Comment: was your question answered, @vinay?

Comment: Not yet gelnacota, im still not clear what can be done inside cognito

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Cognito for authentication, you can check the [documentation to customize the sign-in page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-ui-customization.html).